# В чем ошибка? с#

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Данный код должен во втором текстбоксе выводить наибольшее количество повторяющихся элементов из dataGridView прим.
есть массив 1 2 4 7 9 5 2 2 4
в результате в textBox2 должно выводиться число 3, т.к. число число 2 повторяется больше остальных, а именно 3 раза, вместо этого в textBox2 выводится количество элементов массива.
Как исправить эту ошибку?

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            

            int n = Convert.ToInt16(textBox1.Text);
            int[] a = new int[n];

            var column1 = new DataGridViewColumn();
            column1.HeaderText = "ELEMENTI";
            column1.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column1);
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                a[i] = rnd.Next(10);
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1[0, i].Value = a[i];
            }

            string[] b = new string[dataGridView1.RowCount];
            for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount-2; i++)
            {
                b[i] = dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString();

            }

            int o = 0;
            int date = n;
            int[] arra = new int[date];
            int empare = 0;
            for (int g = 0; g < 11; g++)
            {
                empare = 0;

                for (int q = 0; q <= date-1; q++)
                {
                    if (arra[q] == g)
                    {
                        empare++;
                    }

                }
                if (empare >= 2)
                {
                    while (empare > o)
                    {
                        o++;
                    }
                }
                textBox2.Text = o.ToString();
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: так вы создаете массив, забитый нулями, и потом считаете сколько в нем нулей - вот и получаете длину массива. Но за код такой конечно надо ругать, какая то сплошная мешанина, потому наверное вы и потерялись в нем.

Comment: Можете сказать, в каком месте кода нужно что-то изменить, чтобы он работал корректно?

Comment: мне негде запускать ваш код, и его качество так и останется низким, но я просто предположу, что вот такое изменение может помочь `int[] arra = new int[date];` ==> `int[] arra = a;`

Comment: Работает. Спасибо вам за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Код находит все числа которые встречаются чаще всего. Если числа встречаются в одинаковом количестве (например 3 единицы и 3 шетерки - даст `[1,6]` )

```
    int[] input = { 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8 };

    var result = input
       .GroupBy(i => i)
       .GroupBy(g => g.Count())
       .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
       .First()
       .Select(g => g.Key)
       .ToArray();
```

и не забываем

```
using System.Linq;
```